# Tensorflow op in Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to use a tensorflow op inside a Keras model. I previously tried to wrap it with a Lambda layer but I believe this disables that layers' backpropagation.

More specifically, I'm trying to use the layers from [here](https://github.com/zplizzi/tensorflow-fast-rcnn/tree/master/tensorflow/core/user_ops) in a Keras model, without porting it to Keras layers (I hope to deploy to tensorflow later on). I can compile these layers in a shared library form and load these into python. This gives me tensorflow ops and I don't know how to combine this in a Keras model.

A simple example of a Keras MNIST model, where for example one Conv2D layer is replaced by a tf.nn.conv2d op, would be exactly what I'm looking for.

I've seen [this](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) tutorial but it appears to do the opposite of what I am looking for. It seems to insert Keras layers into a tensorflow graph. I'm looking to do the exact opposite.

Best regards,
Hans

Comment: A `Lambda` layer should not disable backpropagation. What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpreted what happened, but I modified a (working) Keras MNIST example to use tf ops (https://gist.github.com/hgaiser/9d38ac49424f400c161c8086ff864d08). That network didn't seem to train (0.1 acc.). Also, its summary shows no trainable parameters. For clarity, I don't mean my network does not backpropagate at all, just that the Lambda layers do not contribute to the backpropagation. If the network consists of only Lambda layers, there is no training at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly two weeks have passed and it seems I am able to answer my own question now.

It seems like tensorflow can look up gradients if you register them using [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RegisterGradient) decorator. As of writing, this functionality is not (yet) available in C++, which is what I was looking for. A workaround would be to define a normal op in C++ and wrap it in a python method using the mentioned decorator. If these functions with corresponding gradients are registered with tensorflow, backpropagation will happen 'automagically'.